# MYSQL Next/Previous record based on specific sort

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ~21M records.  Among the fields are firstname, lastname, middlename.

If I do a query like

```
SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
FROM table WHERE lastname LIKE 'C%' 
ORDER BY lastname ASC, firstname ASC, middlename ASC;
```

A user can choose the first person whose last name starts with C.  I'm needing to give them the option to go to the previous record which would be the last person with the last name starting with B. I also need to give them the option to go to the next record.

I have attempted to create a sorted table and then create a primary key using the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE tableSorted like tableA;
INSERT INTO tableSorted SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY lastname ASC, firstname ASC, middlename ASC;
ALTER TABLE `tableSorted ` ADD `sortid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

It gives me an ID that I can work with to do the sort. The problem with it is I have to recreate this table nightly and creating the sorted table could take several hours.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this without creating a "sorted ID"?

Comment: I understand you want only three records, and not all the records that start with a `C`: 1) the first one found with a `C`, 2) the previous one, 3) the next one. Is this correct?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: There's absolutely no obligation on the part of the processor to process the rows in the order you think you've specified. One day, this is going to go wrong, and you won't even notice :-(

Comment: You left out the interface and what you mean by "let the user select". Do you need the user to be able to see a preview of some information on the previous record? (such as, in this case the fact that it will being with "b" instead of "c"? Next up: Since you mentioned the need to create the table nightly, It this because you don't want "new records" to interfere with the results when a user is already looking at records? If so, please describe the situation (ie: Why?). Why not use a query that returns ALL records, then find your target record with LIMIT offset, row_count; and use the offset

Comment: We have to rebuild the table nightly because we are required to do so by the company providing the data to us.  Our customers have to have an up to date list that is no more than 24 hours old.

Comment: Let's say the user picks one of the records in the original query.  They realize they picked the wrong one and a feature they want is to be able to step through the records one at a time, both next and previous, until they find the one they intended on picking.  If the original query was lastnames that started with C, eventually with the user going next or previous they're going to get out of the lastnames starting with C. The first lastname starting with D or the last lastname starting with B would not be in the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe, that this is the best way, to do a pagination even with a temporary table

But for your question,, you cqan do something like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableA (firstname TexT , middlename Text , lastname TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tableA VALUES  ('a','b','c2'),('a','b','c3'),('a','b','c1')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
> FROM tableA WHERE lastname LIKE 'c%' 
> ORDER BY lastname ASC, firstname ASC, middlename ASC;
> ```

> ```
> firstname | middlename | lastname
> :-------- | :--------- | :-------
> a         | b          | c1      
> a         | b          | c2      
> a         | b          | c3
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tableAsorted (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,firstname TexT , middlename Text , lastname TEXT )
> SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
> FROM tableA WHERE lastname LIKE 'c%' 
> ORDER BY lastname ASC, firstname ASC, middlename ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tableAsorted
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstname | middlename | lastname
> -: | :-------- | :--------- | :-------
>  1 | a         | b          | c1      
>  2 | a         | b          | c2      
>  3 | a         | b          | c3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bcc8b735df34a19d3f7528479f3c8ae)*

You should make your select and do the pagination at appilication level and run trough an array or list or something similar.

Comment: I can't do pagination at application level because it would require me to read in the whole table.  Even creating a temp table of just the name columns would take a while considering how many records there are.

Comment: @DanT. use my create table query in a stored procedure and SELECT the data from the created temporary table.